How do I solve a homogenous linear equation using SVD when the elements of the matrix are uncertain?
I need to solve the homogenous linear equation:
$$
A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}
$$
for $\mathbf{x}$. I am not interested in the trivial solution $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.
I am using the SVD for this:
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T
$$
I am in control of A by how I design an experiment.
I understand that the columns of V which correspond to zero singular values
form an orthonormal basis for the null space of A.
I see three different cases:

no zero singular values
1 zero singular value
more than one zero singular value

In case 1. there is no exact solution to the equation. However by picking the right singular value corresponding to the least singular value I find the least square error solution to the equation.
In case 2. the basis of the null space of A consists of one vector. I can find an unique solution to the equation by demanding that $||\mathbf{x}||=1$.
In case 3. the basis of the null space of A consists of more than one vector. I can NOT find an unique solution to the equation. I must therefore conclude that my experiment is malformed.
Is my understanding above correct?
However in case 1. I still see a problem. As an example let us assume that the singular values are:
$$
\sigma_1 = 10, \sigma_2 = 1, \sigma_3 = 0.01, \sigma_4 = 0.01 
$$
See that $\sigma_3 = \sigma_4$. Does this mean that the least squares solution to A is not unique? Also due to uncertainties in measurements the same would be true if  $\sigma_3 \approx \sigma_4$?
If so my plan would be to do this: choose an small number $\epsilon$.
Calculate a threshold singular value: $\sigma_T = \epsilon * \sigma_1$. Count the singular values that are below this treshold. If the count is above 1 conclude that the experiment is malformed. If not pick the right singular value corresponding to least singular value as the solution. This solution will then be an exact solution in the case where the least singular value = 0 and a least square error solution in the case where the least singular value > 0?

$x = 0$ is always a solution, in any of the 3 cases

Ooops, I forgot to specify that I am not interested in that solution.

For case 2, $-x$ (or $x e^{i \theta}$ for any $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$ if you are working on complex numbers) is also a solution. But maybe this is “unique enough” for you.
For case 3, you have infinitely many solutions with free parameters. In particular, if the columns of $X$ spans the null space of $A$, then $X y$ is a solution for any $y$. I don’t know about your problem but this might be a good thing. Knowing you have freedom to choose for some parameters, you can optimize for other things such as robustness to uncertainty, etc.
For case 1, if the smallest singular values are close together, this reduces to case 3 as you have observed.
